# auto Increment the last four digit value from the varchar field in php codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

In my database field i have varchar field like this format HPDO1209180000.What i am doing is if i dont have any data i am adding four digits at last it is working fine.And if if it is there  i am incrementing one each time.but the problem is after 0001 also incrementing all the 0001 only not 0002 like that.I am doing like this please help me.thanks in Advance.

```
  $this->db->select('grmno');
        $this->db->from('procurement_receive_material');
        $this->db->where('DATE(createdon)',$currentdate);
        $this->db->where('SUBSTRING(grmno,1,10)',$grn_code);
        $this->db->order_by('prmid','desc');
        $query = $this->db->get();
        if($query->num_rows()>0){
            $output = $query->row();
            $grmNumber = $output->grmno;
      //after 0001 also it incrementing 0001 not incrementing;
            $inrno=str_pad((int)$grmNumber+1, 4, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT); 

                $grmNumber=$vendor_result.$branch_result.$currentDate.$currentmonth.$currentyear.$inrno;
        }else{
            $grmNumber = $vendor_result.$branch_result.$currentDate.$currentmonth.$currentyear.'0000';
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm reading this correctly, it looks like this line:

```
$inrno=str_pad((int)$grmNumber+1, 4, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

Is taking the int value of $output->grmno.  And this field, again if I'm interpreting your problem directly, can be evaluated as something like this:

```
HPDO1209180001
```

The integer value of such a string would be 0.  Hence, why they always end up as 0001.

To fix this, you need to grab the last 4 characters of the string, and increment only that.  For example:

```
$suffix = substr($grmNumber, -4);
$newsuffix = intval($suffix) + 1;
$irno = str_pad($newsuffix, 4, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

This would properly grab the last 4 digits, add one to the value, and again pad it with zeros to be added to the new string.

Comment: I would also like to point out that while the above will work nicely in a controlled environment where this is called in sequence at a steady pace, if you end up getting a lot of traffic through this you won't be able to keep the suffix unique.  2 calls coming in at the same instant could both read the same number, and the insert would then try to write out the same suffix.  If you have a unique index on that column in your DB, it could cause one of the inserts to fail and unless you have adequate code in place to capture the situation, you could lose data.